# Is there any function to find second minimum or maximum number in 2D array?

Tags: python-2.7

I have an 2D array,

```
a= [[ 1  5  9]
 [ 5  8  9]
 [-9  6  2]]
```

I want to find the second minimum or maximum number in this array. for example pad = -9 which is lowest value in this array, I want to get minimum value = 1. 
Ex.

```
if(np.amin(a)== pad):
      min = 1
```

I am looking for one line function which returns the second minimum value.
It should also be able to find answer in below case:

```
k = [-999. -999. -999. -999.   43.   40. -999.   14.   15.]
```

In this case, when we sort

```
k = [-999. -999. -999. -999. -999. 14.   15. 40. 43.]
min = 14
```

**Update 1**

```
nodatavalue = -999.0
if(np.amin(k) == nodatavalue): 
      np.amin(np.array(a)[a != np.amin(a)]) 
else: 
       np.amin(k)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using numpy: `a != np.amin(a)` will give you an index-array of all elements which aren't equal to the minimum. You can use that to mask out the min-values and then call `amin` on the masked array to get your answer:

```
np.amin(np.array(a)[a != np.amin(a)])
```

Note that if your input is a numpy array (and not a python list) you don't need the extra call to `np.array`, making it just:

```
np.amin(a[a != np.amin(a)])
```

**EDIT:** If you want to find the minimum while disregarding a specific value, you can just use that value to generate the index array:

```
np.amin(a[a != nodatavalue])
```

Note that it helps if you ask what you *actually need* the first time around in your question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing useful and clear questions!

Comment: @AN_SH yw! Note that if your original array is already a Numpy array (and not a vanilla python list) then you can omit the extra call to `np.array`

Comment: one more question- how do compare minimum value with given value. for example consider array k in question. here min = -999.0 but what I want is getting the second minimum value, if nodatavalue = -999.0. the code works great for this condition, but I will look for second minimum value only if amin(k)== nodatavalue.

Comment: This miht help understanding,
    if(np.amin(k) == nodatavalue):
           np.amin(np.array(a)[a != np.amin(a)])
    else:
           np.amin(k)
Please check update 1

Comment: I think i asnwered my own question

Comment: You could just use `np.amin(a[a != nodatavalue])`

Comment: its giving min value as nodatavalue.